How to verify if sets satisfying cardinality conditions exist?
I am trying to find out if sets satisfying the following properties exist:

Call the sets $A_1, \ldots, A_{20}$ and $B_1, \ldots, B_{20}$.
For each $i \in \{1, \ldots, 20\}$, $|A_i| \in \{1,2\}, |B_i| = 3 - |A_i|$.
$|A_1 \cup A_2 \ldots \cup B_{20}| = 15$
Each $x \in |A_1 \cup A_2 \ldots \cup B_{20}|$ occurs in exactly 4 of the $A_1 \ldots, B_{20}$

How do I go about doing this? I have tried using Principle of inclusion and exclusion, but it doesn't really seem to help in this scenario, since it gives you the exact cardinality of $A_1 \cup A_2 \ldots \cup B_{20}$ which doesn't help much.
For context, I am trying to generate an algorithm for a computer science project. I don't want to brute force the problem, because I need it to work for higher numbers which might take several hours to compute, so I am wondering if there is a clean mathematical procedure / existence conditions.

As a clarification, does the property number 3 include only $B_{20}$ or all of the $B$s?

@QuantumWiz all of them

Yes, they exist python simulation

Simulposted to MO, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/483730/how-to-verify-if-sets-satisfying-cardinality-condition-exist –PLEASE DON'T DO THAT!

@GerryMyerson the stack exchange post has 5 properties not 4 is more restrictive checkmate

In other words, you are asking whether there is a bipartite graph with $15$ vertices on one side (all of degree $4$) and $40$ vertices on the other side ($20$ of degree $1$ and $20$ of degree $2$.) A criterion for this sort of question is given by the Gale–Ryser theorem.

Whoopee. Look, the problems have so much in common, you have to leave links at each to the other.

For "exactly four" as in the edited question, a mixed-integer linear integer solver gives
A1: [12, 13] ; B1: [2]
A2: [7, 8]   ; B2: [11]
A3: [1, 7]   ; B3: [3]
A4: [5, 9]   ; B4: [1]
A5: [2, 7]   ; B5: [8]
A6: [10, 13] ; B6: [6]
A7: [5, 9]   ; B7: [11]
A8: [2, 4]   ; B8: [2]
A9: [7, 8]   ; B9: [6]
A10: [4, 9]  ; B10: [10]
A11: [3, 14] ; B11: [11]
A12: [1, 5]  ; B12: [12]
A13: [0, 13] ; B13: [6]
A14: [0, 4]  ; B14: [13]
A15: [6, 11] ; B15: [10]
A16: [0, 5]  ; B16: [3]
A17: [4, 9]  ; B17: [1]
A18: [12, 14]; B18: [14]
A19: [0, 12] ; B19: [10]
A20: [3, 14] ; B20: [8]

Element 0 in sets ['A13', 'A14', 'A16', 'A19']
Element 1 in sets ['A3', 'A12', 'B4', 'B17']
Element 2 in sets ['A5', 'A8', 'B1', 'B8']
Element 3 in sets ['A11', 'A20', 'B3', 'B16']
Element 4 in sets ['A8', 'A10', 'A14', 'A17']
Element 5 in sets ['A4', 'A7', 'A12', 'A16']
Element 6 in sets ['A15', 'B6', 'B9', 'B13']
Element 7 in sets ['A2', 'A3', 'A5', 'A9']
Element 8 in sets ['A2', 'A9', 'B5', 'B20']
Element 9 in sets ['A4', 'A7', 'A10', 'A17']
Element 10 in sets ['A6', 'B10', 'B15', 'B19']
Element 11 in sets ['A15', 'B2', 'B7', 'B11']
Element 12 in sets ['A1', 'A18', 'A19', 'B12']
Element 13 in sets ['A1', 'A6', 'A13', 'B14']
Element 14 in sets ['A11', 'A18', 'A20', 'B18']

Edit: A simpler solution is perhaps to start from
A1: [0, 1] ; B1: [1]
A2: [1, 2] ; B2: [0]
A3: [1, 2] ; B3: [0]
A4: [0, 2] ; B4: [2]
Element 0 in sets ['A1', 'A4', 'B2', 'B3']
Element 1 in sets ['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'B1']
Element 2 in sets ['A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'B4']

and to scale this to $4n$ sets and $3n$ unique elements: the 3 elements in the $n$-th group only appear in the 4 sets in the $n$-th group.
The python code used is the following:
from gurobipy import Model, GRB, quicksum

num_sets = 40
num_elements = 15
model = Model("SetProblem")
x = model.addVars(num_sets, num_elements, vtype=GRB.BINARY, name="x")

for j in range(num_elements):
    model.addConstr(quicksum(x[i, j] for i in range(num_sets)) == 4)

for i in range(num_sets // 2):
    model.addConstr(quicksum(x[i, j] for j in range(num_elements)) == 2)
    model.addConstr(quicksum(x[i + (num_sets // 2), j] for j in range(num_elements)) == 1)


model.optimize()

if model.status == GRB.OPTIMAL:
    print("Solution found:")
    names = {}
    for i in range(num_sets//2):
        Ai = [j for j in range(num_elements) if x[i, j].x > 0.5]
        Bi = [j for j in range(num_elements) if x[i + (num_sets//2), j].x > 0.5]
        names[i] = {'name': f'A{i + 1}', 'elements': Ai}
        names[i + (num_sets//2)] = {'name': f'B{i + 1}', 'elements': Bi}
        print(f"    A{i + 1}: {Ai} ; B{i + 1}: {Bi}")
    for j in range(num_elements):
        fours = [i for i in range(num_sets) if x[i, j].x > 0.5]
        assert len(fours) == 4
        print('    Element', j, 'in sets', [names[i]['name'] for i in fours])

else:
    print("No solution found.")


What is a mixed linear integer solver? How do I use it?

Is there a textbook on it

I am not the poster of the answer, but I assume this is how to go about it: There are 15 elements and 40 sets, so you can encode a solution using $15\times 40$ variables $x_{ij}$ taking values in ${0,1}$ and encoding whether the $i$-th element is in the $j$-th set. The various constraints can be phrased as a list of inequalities and equalities for suitable sums of these variables. Problems of this form (finding solutions to a system of linear inequalities, with some or all variables integers), are called "(mixed) integer linear programs", and there is various software to solve these.

@AchimKrause is spot on. I added the code to the answer.

The answer to the updated question is yes.  Let $|A_i|=1$ for all $i \in [20]$ with $|\bigcup_{i \in [20]} A_i|=15$. If we view each $B_i$ as an edge of a graph on 15 vertices, then it suffices to find a graph on 15 vertices with 10 degree-3 vertices and 5 degree-2 vertices. Such a graph clearly exists. For example, take the disjoint union of the Petersen graph and a 5-cycle.

I made an error in the post it was exactly 4 not 3

@bof I made error in the post

You don't need anything too fancy, you just want 40 subsets of $\{1,2,\cdots, 15\}$. Half of size 1 and half of size 2 and using each element $4$ times. How about each of
$\{1,2\},\{3,4\},\{5,6\},\{7,8\},\{9,10\},$
$\{11\},\{12\},\{13\},\{14\},\{15\}$
four times each.
Alternately, start with $60$ elements , $1,2,\cdots,15$ four times each, say a red , green , blue and orange copy or each value. Then group them into $40$ disjoint sets of sizes $1$ and $2$ never putting two of the same value in a pair. Then forget the colors.
